# IOS send email in backend

Tags: ios, swift, email

I have 2 text fields and a send button in a view for reporting explicit content on my app. I want my app to send me an email if the send button is pressed and it should send the contents of both text fields. Is there some swift tool for sending these in the backend?

I have searched elsewhere for answers, but can't find a recent answer anywhere concerning backend email sending with swift apps.

This question has been asked a few times in different ways, but its been like 4 years since it was last asked and I am wondering if anything has changed.

I am using swift and the most recent version of xcode.

Button action so far:

```
@IBAction func sendReport(sender: AnyObject) {
    let username:String = offendingUserUsername.text!
    let reportText:String = reportContent.text!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sending emails from your app you need a **Transactional email delivery service**.

A great service for that is **[SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/)**. It is very powerful and easy to implement into your app with **[this library](https://github.com/scottkawai/sendgrid-swift)**.

It also has a **Free** plan that lets you send up to 12k emails per month.
You can find the Free plan [**here**](https://sendgrid.com/marketing/mandrill-alternative)

Comment: Thanks, Ill accept this answer in 30 mins if no one can make a simple code answer.